# OnInitialize vs PersistentPreRun in a Cobra-based CLI

Tags: go, go-cobra

I'm working with the [Cobra](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/cobra#Command.Flag) library for Go. The README [shows an example](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/master/user_guide.md#using-the-cobra-library) that handles configuration setup via the `cobra.OnInitialize` function. The documentation for `OnInitialize` says:

> OnInitialize sets the passed functions to be run when each command's Execute method is called.

But isn't that pretty much exactly the same thing as registering a `PersistentPreRun` function on the root command? That will also run just before the `Execute` method on any command.

Comment: There seem to be several oddities like this in spf13/cobra. I suspect Hysterical Raisins myself.

Comment: Actually, I suspect that the difference is that while you can only have one active `PersistentPreRun` (that is, setting it on a child will override one set on a parent), you can call `cobra.OnInitialize` multiple times and all the registered functions will be called. I have yet to verify this.

Comment: Interesting, but that could be the historical reason (someone needed one behavior when only the other was available). I do wish the documentation were clearer.